# Scaling of inline SVG previews in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex, previewing

If I insert a jpg in my org-mode document, I can preview it and scale its width, like so:

Add the following code to my `init.el` file:

```
(setq org-image-actual-width nil)
```

Then insert this code in my document, where I want the image to appear:

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 300
[[./my_image.jpg]]
```

On executing `org-toggle-inline-images` the image appears in the buffer, 300px wide, as expected.

But if I attempt this same operation with an SVG file, I get a blank placeholder. If I then remove the `#+ATTR_ORG` tag, the SVG appears. (at it's pre-defined width)...

Can anyone tell me how I can resize my SVGs image previews? I am running the [macports version of Emacs](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/releases) version 25.1 on El Capitan.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Emacs StackExchange! Does this issue still occur when you start Emacs with a minimal init file? (That is, start with `emacs -Q` and load *only* the libraries related to your question.) If not, please try to [bisect your init file](//meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/204/675).

Comment: Thanks Scott! My init.el is quite length. So I started a fresh init.el file and added `(setq org-image-actual-width nil)`. This enables the width attribute on JPGs but has no effect on SVGs...

Comment: Thanks for confirming. (Feel free to [edit] that info into your post so that it can be found more easily.) Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with embedded images in org-mode to be any more help at this point.

Comment: Can you check if svg is included in imagemagick-types? I. E.  C-h v imagemagick-types.

Comment: Ah no, it's not on the list. But the macports edition of Emacs relies on the WebKit framework to render SVGs... [Here is a blurb about it](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/overview).